# UWP application hangs when using multiple Webviews with heavy URLs

Tags: c#, uwp

I have to rotate between URLs(lets say 10 urls). Every url has its own Webview and each webview is shown for 15 secs(one at a time). I can change the urls from the server and that immediately shows onto the UWP application.

If the internet is out, the WebViews should still rotate between all the urls after the interval that is why we are using multiple webviews.

Currently, the situation is, that the more URLs I change, the more RAM it takes and eventually hangs.

Answer (score 0):

[`WebViews`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) is heavyweight control, please don't create multiple instance to render html page, for the scenario, you could use timer to change one webview's source with mvvm pattern for each 15s. Even if the internet is out, it will still work. Please check the following code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        initUri();
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
        Source = new Uri("xxxxxx");

    }
    private List<Uri> _uris = new List<Uri>();
    private void initUri()
    {

        _uris.Add(new Uri("xxxxxx"));
        _uris.Add(new Uri("xxxxxx"));
        _uris.Add(new Uri("xxxxxx"));       

    }

    int count = 0;
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {

        Source = _uris[count];
        count++;
        if (count == _uris.Count)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private Uri _source;
    public Uri Source
    {
        get
        {
            return _source;
        }

        set
        {
            _source = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<WebView
    x:Name="MyWebView"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Source="{x:Bind Source, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a question here, how would the new source URI load in the timer callback when we do not have the internet. How are we caching them? I have to keep rotating between the Uris after internet is no longer available.

Comment: During the internet disconnect, the timer still work, it will load the url, but it will not get the response, if the internet does not resume in 15s, the webview will load the next one until the internet resume